# Jquery Datatable plugin not working on html table

Tags: datatables

I am trying to use the DataTable plugin to add functionality to my html table. I followed the steps for installation and initialization from datatables.net, but it is not adding any functionality to my html page. I am wondering if it is because my table is formatted in a way that isn't supported by the plug-in.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
        } 
        );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are loading the dataTable.js **before** jQuery. (you can see the problem in the webconsole of your browser (usually, when typing <kbd>F12</kbd>). Loading jQuery before will solve your problem:

```
<!-- first jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- then dataTables -->
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
        } 
        );
    </script>
```